# How to run a mobile Flex application in BlackBerry BB STORM 9530?

Tags: configure, blackberry-storm, flash-builder4.5

[image]

I am developing mobile Flex Google Map related application. This application Android device working fine.

I am using tools Flashbuilder 4.5 integrated to Eclipse. Android device working fine. I am test to BlackBerry device (BB STORM 9530) connect to my pc sign key also completed in configure the device display one popup.

This window show the device IP and debug host IP. How can get in these IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Flash or Flex in any form with Storm and other BB handhelds